# Angular waiting - script runs repeatedly

Tags: angular, selenium, robotframework

I am using selenium lib and angular lib with robot framework, and I use a simple step: Click Element |  locator. In the log, I see that a (same) script run several(26) times due to the test will be very slow.
So the question is why run the same script so much?

Comment: Hi, Please make sure to add more detailed information in the question so that others can help you on your query. You can add snippet of code which caused error and step you followed. Please refer [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ~Thanks

Comment: Why the js script runs so many times? when i use angular lib